# Align edges of forest to center of column in node

Tags: forest, trees

I have a `forest` whose nodes are `tabular`s, looking like this:

[image]

I would like the edges to

1. be aligned to the center of the second column of the table (the
   formulas) -- that is, at the upper end, the center of the second
   column of the parent table and at the lower end, the center of the
   second column of the child table -- rather than the center of the
   node, which is the center of the entire table width;
2. *-- solved with js bibra's answer --* start right in the center rather than with some distance symmetrically around the center, so that the edges to all children meet at the top:

[image]

I know that there is an option to set the `anchor`s, but how do I point it to the center of a column inside the node? I suppose I could set `\tikzmark`s and have the edge start and end at `lastformulaparent.center`, `firstformulachild.center`, respectively, but how, if at all, could I do this generically without having to set new tikzmarks and custom edges for every node?

```
\documentclass{article}

% math formatting
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amstext}

% tableau trees
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{qtree/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south: 
           child anchor=north,align=center,inner sep=0pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\underline{1.} & $\neg \exists y \forall x P(x{,}\ \!y)$ & (A)\\
\underline{2.} & $\forall x \exists y P(x{,}\ \!y)$ & (A)\\
\underline{3.} & $\exists y P(a{,}\ \!y)$ & ($\forall{,}\ 2{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack*$)\\
\underline{4.} & $\neg \forall x P(x{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\neg \exists{,}\ 1{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)
\end{tabular}
    [
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    5. & $\neg P(a{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 4{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack$)
    \end{tabular}
        [
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        6. & $P(a{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\exists{,}\ 3{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
        & $\times$ & ($5{,}\ 6$)
        \end{tabular}
        ]
    ]
    [
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \underline{7.} & \underline{$\neg P(b{,}\ \!a)$} & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 4{,}\ \lbrack x/b \rbrack*$)
    \end{tabular}
        [
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \underline{8.} & \underline{$P(a{,}\ \!a)$} & ($\exists{,}\ 3{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
        \underline{9.} & $\exists y P(b{,}\ \!y)$ & ($\forall{,}\ 2{,}\ \lbrack x/b \rbrack$)
        \end{tabular}
            [
            \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            10. & $P(b{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\exists{,}\ 9{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
            & $\times$ & ($7{,}\ 10$)
            \end{tabular}
            ]
            [
            \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            \underline{11.} & \underline{$P(b{,}\ \!b)$} & ($\exists{,}\ 9{,}\ \lbrack y/b \rbrack$)\\
            \underline{12.} & $\neg \forall x P(x{,}\ \!b)$ & ($\neg \exists{,}\ 1{,}\ \lbrack y/b \rbrack$)
            \end{tabular}
                [
                \begin{tabular}{lcl}
                \underline{13.} & \underline{$\neg P(a{,}\ \!b)$} & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 12{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack$)\\
                \underline{} & $\circ$ &
                \end{tabular}
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your `qtree` style: it should read `anchor=south,` not `anchor=south:`. And you need to apply it to your tree by using `\begin{forest}qtree ...`. This is what @jsbibra's solution does, effectively so you had the solution at hand already.

Comment: But if you load `forest` with the `linguistics` option, that will be the default style anyway.

Comment: @Alan Munn Oh, that makes sense. I'll go with the linguistics option then; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon js bibra's answer, you can set the first and third columns of each tabular to the same fixed value (change `lcl` to `p{1em}cp{1em}`); the centre of each tabular will then be the centre of the formula column.

As far as I can tell there are a few minor prices to pay for doing this: you have to live with a couple of `Overfull \hbox` complaints, and you need to add some `s sep` keys at appropriate points in the tree to stop branches colliding (see lines 23 and 43 in the code below).

But at least the output is finally pleasingly aligned.

Interested readers might like to refer to my question at [Nice alignment across nodes in logic proof trees typeset with forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570449/nice-alignment-across-nodes-in-logic-proof-trees-typeset-with-forest) for a way of doing something like this that avoids having to create multirow tabulars (although there are some tradeoffs).

[image: The centres of the formulas are now pleasingly aligned down the middle of the branch]

```
\documentclass{article}

% math formatting
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amstext}

% tableau trees
\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={for tree={parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            inner sep=0pt}}
[
\begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
\underline{1.} & $\neg \exists y \forall x P(x{,}\ \!y)$ & (A)\\
\underline{2.} & $\forall x \exists y P(x{,}\ \!y)$ & (A)\\
\underline{3.} & $\exists y P(a{,}\ \!y)$ & ($\forall{,}\ 2{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack*$)\\
\underline{4.} & $\neg \forall x P(x{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\neg \exists{,}\ 1{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)
\end{tabular}, s sep=6em
    [
    \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
    5. & $\neg P(a{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 4{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack$)
    \end{tabular}
        [
        \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
        6. & $P(a{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\exists{,}\ 3{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
        & $\times$ & ($5{,}\ 6$)
        \end{tabular}
        ]
    ]
    [
    \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
    \underline{7.} & \underline{$\neg P(b{,}\ \!a)$} & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 4{,}\ \lbrack x/b \rbrack*$)
    \end{tabular}
        [
        \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
        \underline{8.} & \underline{$P(a{,}\ \!a)$} & ($\exists{,}\ 3{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
        \underline{9.} & $\exists y P(b{,}\ \!y)$ & ($\forall{,}\ 2{,}\ \lbrack x/b \rbrack$)
        \end{tabular}, s sep=5em
            [
            \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
            10. & $P(b{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\exists{,}\ 9{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
            & $\times$ & ($7{,}\ 10$)
            \end{tabular}
            ]
            [
            \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
            \underline{11.} & \underline{$P(b{,}\ \!b)$} & ($\exists{,}\ 9{,}\ \lbrack y/b \rbrack$)\\
            \underline{12.} & $\neg \forall x P(x{,}\ \!b)$ & ($\neg \exists{,}\ 1{,}\ \lbrack y/b \rbrack$)
            \end{tabular}
                [
                \begin{tabular}{p{1em}cp{1em}}
                \underline{13.} & \underline{$\neg P(a{,}\ \!b)$} & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 12{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack$)\\
                \underline{} & $\circ$ &
                \end{tabular}
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `\forestset` in the preamble

```
\forestset{qtree/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south: 
           child anchor=north,align=center,inner sep=0pt}}}
```

And add the following definition after `\begin{document}`

```
for tree={for tree={parent anchor=south,
        child anchor=north,
        align=center,
        inner sep=0pt}}
```

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

% math formatting
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amstext}

% tableau trees
\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={for tree={parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            inner sep=0pt}}
[
\begin{tabular}{lcl}
\underline{1.} & $\neg \exists y \forall x P(x{,}\ \!y)$ & (A)\\
\underline{2.} & $\forall x \exists y P(x{,}\ \!y)$ & (A)\\
\underline{3.} & $\exists y P(a{,}\ \!y)$ & ($\forall{,}\ 2{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack*$)\\
\underline{4.} & $\neg \forall x P(x{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\neg \exists{,}\ 1{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)
\end{tabular}
    [
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    5. & $\neg P(a{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 4{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack$)
    \end{tabular}
        [
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        6. & $P(a{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\exists{,}\ 3{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
        & $\times$ & ($5{,}\ 6$)
        \end{tabular}
        ]
    ]
    [
    \begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \underline{7.} & \underline{$\neg P(b{,}\ \!a)$} & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 4{,}\ \lbrack x/b \rbrack*$)
    \end{tabular}
        [
        \begin{tabular}{lcl}
        \underline{8.} & \underline{$P(a{,}\ \!a)$} & ($\exists{,}\ 3{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
        \underline{9.} & $\exists y P(b{,}\ \!y)$ & ($\forall{,}\ 2{,}\ \lbrack x/b \rbrack$)
        \end{tabular}
            [
            \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            10. & $P(b{,}\ \!a)$ & ($\exists{,}\ 9{,}\ \lbrack y/a \rbrack$)\\
            & $\times$ & ($7{,}\ 10$)
            \end{tabular}
            ]
            [
            \begin{tabular}{lcl}
            \underline{11.} & \underline{$P(b{,}\ \!b)$} & ($\exists{,}\ 9{,}\ \lbrack y/b \rbrack$)\\
            \underline{12.} & $\neg \forall x P(x{,}\ \!b)$ & ($\neg \exists{,}\ 1{,}\ \lbrack y/b \rbrack$)
            \end{tabular}
                [
                \begin{tabular}{lcl}
                \underline{13.} & \underline{$\neg P(a{,}\ \!b)$} & ($\neg \forall{,}\ 12{,}\ \lbrack x/a \rbrack$)\\
                \underline{} & $\circ$ &
                \end{tabular}
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves the second part; thanks!

Comment: This is the same style as the `qtree` style in the question, except that there was a typo in that style and it hadn't been applied to the tree anyway. So a simpler solution is fix the style and apply it to the tree.

Comment: But this style isn't needed at all if `forest` is loaded with the `linguistics` option.